# If NETFX_CORE is for Windows 8, what is for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-phone-8, conditional-compilation

I understand using the NETFX_CORE directive, like this:

```
#if NETFX_CORE 
    // Windows 8
#else 
    // Windows Phone 8
#endif
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714084(v=vs.105).aspx

But is there a directive specific to Windows Phone 8?

Comment: The link is for .NET development, but the question wasn't tagged either way. Am I right this is primarily about .NET? Native development will have different defines.

Comment: Um, NETFX_CORE sort of implies the tech, sorry if you missed that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Windows Phone directive is:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
```

This is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469.aspx), but I'm surprised that it isn't mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714084(v=vs.105).aspx).  I also tested this in some code, and it works.

Comment: And for projects targeting **Windows 8.1** and **Windows Phone 8.1** these will be `WINDOWS_APP` and `WINDOWS_PHONE_APP`.

Answer (score 4):

WP8 should use custom conditional compilation flags introduced by the developer. Read more about this exact topic [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html;#toc_Compiletimeadaptation). Nokia has an entire article dedicated to [coding for both WP7 and WP8](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html) and I highly recommend you go over all techniques to see what's the best one for you to use.

> Defining conditional compilation symbol:
>
> 1. Right click on the WP 8 project and select Properties. 
>      Open up the
> 2. Build page of Project Designer and insert WP8 into Conditional
>      compilation symbols. After this, they should contain something like
>      this: **SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;WP8**

And here's the inline code sample

```
// Separate implementations for different OS versions
#if WP8
    // code using enhancements introduced in Windows Phone 8 
#else
    // code using Windows Phone OS 7.1 features 
#endif


// A new Windows Phone 8 feature
#if WP8
    // code using new Windows Phone 8 feature
#endif
```

Comment: can you please help me i have same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094143/macros-in-prefix-pch-file-equivalent-in-wp8

Comment: Do you mean #UNITY_WP8 or is WP8 different?  If you meant UNITY_WP8 then this is incorrect as it should be WINDOWS_PHONE: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/whats-the-difference-between-if-unity_wp8-and-if-windows_phone.221061/

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, there is not such directive. But you can use if not :

```
#if !NETFX_CORE 
    // Windows Phone 8
#endif
```

Comment: Haha! Not exactly what I meant, but that's funny.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a directive specific to Windows Phone 8?

You can define your own preprocessor directives you know. WINDOWS_PHONE just happens to be defined by the Visual Studio project templates for Windows Phone projects.

Same goes for DEBUG, TRACE and whatever custom ones you might have like EXTENSIVE_LOGGING or LOOKING_FOR_A_CATBUS