# Is there a compiler constant for Windows Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is there a specific compiler constant for WinRT similar to the compiler constant of SILVERLIGHT and WINDOWS_PHONE?

Example:

```
#if SILVERLIGHT

#if WINDOWS_PHONE
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13594472/1136211).

Comment: They exist, easy to see from Project + Properties, Build tab.  Targeting Silverlight or Phone is otherwise never an accident.  Nor do you typically ignore the specific version you target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WINAPI_PARTITION_APP and WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP are the two built in #defines I use.  here is a line to MSDN with more information:

- [MSDN Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/18/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games-part-3.aspx)

EDIT: the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292199/when-does-if-winapi-family-partitionwinapi-partition-desktop-in-dxvahd-h-micr) SO question also has some relevant info:

EDIT: for C# you can use NETFX_CORE (sorry missed the tag in the question).  You need to make sure this is configured in VisualStudio's build tab:

[image]

Comment: But these directives only apply to C++, right? I believe the OP was asking for C# compiler directives.

Comment: Yep you are correct.  I don't know why I assumed this was for c++.  Updated my answer thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The constant that is defined in Windows Store C# projects is `NETFX_CORE`. So you could do this:

```
#if NETFX_CORE
    // Windows Store Apps, Windows Runtime stuff
#end
```