# Macros in Prefix.pch file - equivalent in WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, macros, windows-phone

In iOS applications we use same code. I was able to refer the common classes and separate the application name, theme,color etc using the values from the Prefix.pch file.

```
#define APPLICATION_NAME @"ABC"
#define APPLICATION_THEME @"RED"
#define SUPPORTS_ICLOUD 0
```

By using these macros defined my prefix file, in my program I can say

```
#if SUPPORTS_ICLOUD = 0

-do this stuff-
```

I would like to follow the same approach in WP8.

I found that we can just set it in the `project properties in the menu Build->Conditional compilation Symbols:`.

But i have around 50+ macros defined and its hard to add it in `Build->Conditional compilation Symbols` to add and delete it.

So What is the best approach that i can follow ?

Comment: How many targets you have? Are you creating many applications from a single template?

Comment: @ToniPetrina many, yes i have a template and creating many applications from that

Comment: Since C# doesn't include files the way C++ does it, I am afraid that there is no easy way for you to do that. You will either have to create a new target with different compilation symbols or you will have to generate new .csproj files for each target.

Comment: this is a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306471/how-to-use-prefix-pch-in-wp8-like-in-ios/21310614?noredirect=1#comment33512746_21310614